# SQL Server find the last week of the last 2 months

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
INSERT INTO @blah (ID, Date)
    VALUES (123, '11/12/2012')
    VALUES (124, '11/30/2012')
    VALUES (125, '11/28/2012')
    VALUES (126, '12/1/2012')
    VALUES (127, '12/30/2012')
    VALUES (128, '12/25/2012')
    VALUES (129, '12/26/2012')
```

I want to get rows where the date is the last week of the respective month going back two months.  This month is Jan 2013, so i want the last week of Dec 2012 and Nov 2012.

The ultimate option would be the last full week of a month example: dec 2012 = 12/23-12/29 but for now ill take the last 7 days of the month.

I know how to get the last two months but unsure how to get the last week of the respective month..

```
select
    *
from
    @blah
where
    dateDiff(month,date,getdate()) < 2 ---only look at the last two months
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: select
 *
from
 @blah
where
 dateDiff(month,date,getdate()) < 2 ---only look at the last two months

Comment: How do _you_ define the "last week"?  The last seven days of the month?  A contiguous group of seven days starting on a Sunday that does not run past the end of the month?  Something else?

Comment: thats a good question.. let's do that last week starting on a sunday (even if it pushing into the next month)

Comment: In Dec 2012 last week = 54 and in Nov 2012 = 49?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This meets the stated requirement (last full week of previous two months):

```
SET DATEFIRST 1;

DECLARE @s DATE = GETDATE(), @s1 DATE, @s2 DATE;
SET @s = GETDATE();

-- last day of last month:
SET @s1 = DATEADD(DAY, -DAY(@s), @s);

-- last day of previous month:
SET @s = DATEADD(MONTH, -1, @s);
SET @s2 = DATEADD(DAY, -DAY(@s), @s);

SELECT 
 @s1 = DATEADD(DAY, -7, DATEADD(DAY, -DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @s1) % 7, @s1)),
 @s2 = DATEADD(DAY, -7, DATEADD(DAY, -DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @s2) % 7, @s2));

SELECT col1, col2, etc. 
FROM dbo.table
  WHERE 
  (date_column >= @s1 AND date_column < DATEADD(DAY, 7, @s1)
  OR
  (date_column >= @s2 AND date_column < DATEADD(DAY, 7, @s2);
```

To make this more dynamic (you should do your best to state these requirements FIRST, not after people have put in a bunch of work), you can say:

```
DECLARE @NumberOfMonthsIReallyWanted INT = 3;

DECLARE @i INT = 1, @d DATE = GETDATE();
DECLARE @t TABLE(d DATE);

WHILE @i <= @NumberOfMonthsIReallyWanted
BEGIN
  SET @d = DATEADD(MONTH, -@i, @d)

  INSERT @t(s) SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -7, DATEADD(DAY,  
   -DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(DAY, -DAY(@d), @d)) % 7, 
   DATEADD(DAY, -DAY(@d), @d)));

  SET @i += 1;
END

SELECT src.col1, src.col2, etc. 
  FROM dbo.table AS src
  INNER JOIN @t AS t
  ON src.date_column >= t.d AND src.date_column < DATEADD(DAY, 7, t.d);
```

Please don't let anyone convince you to use `LIKE` for date comparison queries. Not only does this kill sargability (meaning no index can be used), but, for a problem like this, how do you determine what string patterns to match? The difficulty is not in constructing the `WHERE` clause, but rather what to fill in for the magic `(Your Dates go here)` placeholder. And when you do find the range of dates, do you really want 14 individual `LIKE` expressions? I wouldn't.

Comment: I would never use LIKE for any date and especially not this example.  Thank you for your answer - it worked perfectly!

Comment: I might be asking for a lot here but any way to make the count more dynamic.. example: last 3 months

Comment: Thank you again.. very sorry about the requirements

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @blah table (ID int, [Date] datetime)
INSERT INTO @blah (ID, [Date])
select 123, '20121112'
union select 124, '20121130'
union select 125, '20121128'
union select 126, '20121201'
union select 127, '20121230'
union select 128, '20121225'
union select 129, '20121226'

select ID, [Date], datepart(week, [Date])
from @blah
where
    datediff(month, [Date], getdate()) in (1,2)
    and
    datepart(week, [Date]) = datepart(
                                week, 
                                dateadd(
                                    day, 
                                    -datepart(day,dateadd(month, 1, [Date])), 
                                    dateadd(month, 1, [Date])))
```

Answer (score 0):

This works in Oracle - may give you some ideas and hopefully helps:

```
-- Last weeks of last two months -- 
SELECT mydate
  , TRUNC(mydate, 'iw') wk_starts
  , TRUNC(mydate, 'iw') + 7 - 1/86400 wk_ends
  , TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (mydate, 'IW')) ISO_wk#  
 FROM
  ( -- Last week = Last day of the year (hardcoded) - 1 week --
   SELECT(CASE WHEN start_date = To_Date('12/31/2012', 'mm/dd/yyyy') THEN start_date-7 ELSE start_date END) mydate 
     FROM
     ( -- Last 2 months --
      SELECT Add_Months(Last_Day(Trunc(SYSDATE)), - LEVEL) start_date
        FROM dual
     CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2
    )
 )
/
```

Answer (score -3):

This is somewhat dependent on your sql server. This example is similar to Oracle.  Each server has its own functions, like SYSDATE and NOW.

For example.

```
SELECT * from blah WHERE TO_CHAR(TRUNC(data), MM/DD/YYYY) < '01/14/2013'
```

Comment: MS SQL Server 2008 - sorry

Comment: TO_CHAR and TRUNC are not SQL Server functions.

Comment: @DrM: This might be good for Oracle but the question has an SQL-Server tag.