# How would I select the last part week of a month?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a table with employee time/customer information by day.  I need to take that information and summarize it by week and by month.  This I can do.

Where I am stuck is, for the last week of each month I need to take this information, if it is a part week (ending before Saturday), and extract this info and insert into a table or create a view.

These are the fields in the table.
     EmployeeID, TypeOfPay, Warehouse, UserName, WorkedHours, WorkedDate,      WeekEnding, DayOfWeek

Answer (score 0):

Look to these discussions:

[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352313/how-to-calculate-last-week-of-month-by-weekno-and-year-in-sql), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14325261/sql-server-find-the-last-week-of-the-last-2-months)

They show how to get the last sunday of the mounth.
You can have a condition where you state something like:

WHERE DAY(currentDay) > DAY(lastSunday) 
        AND MONTH(currentDay) = MONTH(lastSunday)

Answer (score 0):

Check this: [MSDN DATEPART()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx)

```
;WITH Sell as (
SELECT CAST('20150826' as Date) dt, 1 Amount UNION ALL
SELECT '20150827' dt, 5 Amount UNION ALL
SELECT '20150828' dt, 4 Amount UNION ALL
SELECT '20150829' dt, 8 Amount UNION ALL
SELECT '20150901' dt, 9 Amount UNION ALL
SELECT '20150902' dt, 11 Amount UNION ALL
SELECT '20150903' dt, 3 Amount UNION ALL
SELECT '20150904' dt, 6 Amount UNION ALL
SELECT '20150905' dt, 7 Amount 
)

SELECT 
     DATEPART(MONTH, dt) as mnth
    , DATEPART(WEEK, dt) as wk
    ,SUM(Amount) as Sum
FROM Sell
GROUP BY DATEPART(MONTH, dt)
    , DATEPART(WEEK, dt) 
ORDER BY 1,2
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help.

I ended up creating a calendar and added an accrual column and marked the part weeks at the end of the month with a 2.  I was able then to select the part week by joining the two tables.